# I'm getting a java.text.ParseException in my Swing program

Tags: java, swing

My jdatechooser auto display date like this:
[image: My jdatechooser auto display date like this]

This is my code:

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

    try {
        // display the selected row data in the text felds

        // get the jtable model
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        int rIndex = jTable1.getSelectedRow();

        //display data
        txtID.setText(model.getValueAt(rIndex, 0).toString());
        txtClientID.setText(model.getValueAt(rIndex, 1).toString());
        txtRoomNumber.setText(model.getValueAt(rIndex, 2).toString());


        //display the datein and dateout in jtable to jdatechooser

        Date dateIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse((String)model.getValueAt(rIndex, 3));
        jDateChooserDateIn.setDate(dateIn);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ManageReservationsForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

And this is the error:

```
Mar 23, 2020 8:33:31 PM JFrame.ManageReservationsForm jTable1MouseClicked
SEVERE: null
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2020-03-25"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at JFrame.ManageReservationsForm.jTable1MouseClicked(ManageReservationsForm.java:306)
    at JFrame.ManageReservationsForm.access$000(ManageReservationsForm.java:22)
    at JFrame.ManageReservationsForm$2.mouseClicked(ManageReservationsForm.java:136)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6542)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4544)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Look at the date format used in your data and compare it with the date format that you specify in your `SimpleDateFormat`, notice anything? The error message should have been a pretty strong hint to look into that as well.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thank you sir, i made it

Comment: More to the point: Ask yourself whether `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")` can parse `"2020-03-25"`.